# JavaScript Object add-key value, Same method, different result

Tags: javascript

thanx for read me. Excuse my english and my question maybe stupid.
I'm setting up a cart for a e-shop. I'm trying to catch data from products displayed for create a orderlist. The cart is an object with 3 equals methods for add quantity, name and price. But only one work. Two others overwrite data.

Datas that i want to stock are strings.

```
var Cart = function () {

    this.cartListQte = {}

    this.products_names = {}

    this.products_prices = {}

}
```

//class

```
Cart.prototype = {

    //properties

    'cartListQte': {},

    'products_names': {},

    'products_prices': {},

    //methods

        //setter getter

    setCartListQte: function (cartListQte) {

        this.cartListQte = cartListQte;

    },

    getCartListQte: function () {

        return this.cartListQte;

    },

    setProducts_names: function (products_names) {

        this.products_names = products_names;

    },

    getProducts_names: function () {

        return this.products_names;

    },

    setProducts_prices: function (products_prices) {

        this.products_prices = products_prices;

    },

    getProducts_prices: function () {

        return this.products_prices;

    },

        //"push" new product

    pushed: function (productId,Qty){

        this.cartListQte[parseInt(productId)]= parseInt(Qty);

    },


    pushName: function (productId,nm){

        this.products_names[parseInt(productId)]= nm;

    },


    pushPrice: function (productId,prx){

        this.products_prices[parseInt(productId)]= parseInt(prx);

    }

}
```

//gestion du panier

function addProductToCart (event) {

```
//nouveau panier

var cart = new Cart;

    //on récupère le panier déjà enregisté

var curentCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('panier'));

    //si il existe, on le manipule

if(curentCart != null){

    cart.cartListQte = curentCart.cartListQte;

}

//récupération des nouvelles données à enregistrer

var id = $(this).attr('productid');

var quantity = $("[productIdQte="+id+"]").val();

console.log(quantity);

var name = String($(".name"+id).text());

console.log(name);

var price = $(".price"+id).text();

console.log(parseInt(price));

    //poussées dans le tableau

if(quantity>0){

    /* exemple who don't work too

    var quantity = "1";

    var name = "a";

    var price = "1" ;

    */
    cart.pushed(id, quantity);

    cart.pushName(id, name);

    cart.pushPrice(id, price);

    //écrasement des données dans le local

    localStorage.setItem('panier', JSON.stringify(cart));

    console.log(cart.cartListQte); 

}
```

I expect the output of

```
cart {

  cartListQte: Object { 5: 4, 6: 3 }

  products_names: Object { 5: "toto", 6: "titi" }

  products_prices: Object { 5: 100, 6: 150 }

}
```

but the actual output is

```
cart {

  cartListQte: Object { 5: 4, 6: 3 }

  products_names: Object { 6: "titi" }

  products_prices: Object { 6: 150 }

}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, probably there's something wrong somewhere else. Could you add the snippet where you create the object cart and change ids, prices and names? By the way you should expect product_prices as { 5: null, 6: 150 } cause parseInt can't solve "tata" in pushPrice method.

Comment: While waiting some updates, if you want this behaviour { 5: "tata", 6: 150 } in prices property instead of this one { 5: null, 6: 150 }, change "parseInt(prx)" in "parseInt(prx) ? parseInt(prx) : prx";

Comment: Sorry, i don't have seen you're comment :s. It's my first time here...

Comment: maybe a problem like passing by Reference or passing by value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, this should do the trick.
You forgot to update the 2 other arrays.

```js
if(curentCart != null){

    cart.cartListQte = curentCart.cartListQte;
    cart.products_names = curentCart.products_names;
    cart.products_prices = curentCart.products_prices;

}
```

Comment: No prob ;). I think it's common to think that the problem is bigger than what it really is. At that stage is better asking a second opinion :).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are replacing content in objects.

```
setProducts_names: function (products_names) {
    this.products_names = products_names;
    // all names are replaced with one actuall setting
},
```

so the code needs to be updated with three-dot operator which copies all attributes within the previously stored object

```
setProducts_names: function (products_names) {
    this.products_names = {...this.products_names,...products_names}; 
    // products_names will be merged
},
```

This needst o be added to every `set...` method

Comment: Actually this shouldn't work cause set methods in this particular case are never triggered: @Gauthier with push methods is changing just one array's element so the array is set just the first time and its instance never change.

Comment: yes i don't need seters. The magical think is that the first method work and not second and third ... With same value and same synthax it's very strange.

Comment: @Gauthier as I said in the comment under your question, your prototype is correct (you can see that from this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uzv2t7?file=index.js)). You should show us how you change ids, names and prices before pushing them into your cart object.

Comment: Sorry guys, there was just part of the code when I was answering this :)